# Django - Python: Get sum from 2 fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

In html template I have 3 fields (defined in models.py): `A, B and C`. It is a form. I want field `C` to have a sum of `A + B` when user types some value. 

Is that something I can do with python or it is necessary JavaScript?

Comment: Well you normally use Python as the backend: that is something that answers a request to the user. JavaScript is usually used at the frontend. That are the parts that work in the browser of your screen. Since you probably want to update it live, there is probably no request to the server (well sending a request to sum up two numbers is rather inefficient). So Javacript is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use JavaScript since it's in the front-end. Setup a jQuery listener so that once elements A & B are modified the value C is also modified.

```
$('#A, #B').on('input',function(e){
    $('#C').val(parseInt($('#A').val()) + parseInt($('#B').val()));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4c1jd6ar/

Comment: Appreciated it. So I will use JS and I will set up field C as hidden, so user will not be able to change the value. Field C is Total Working hours in my app.

Comment: You're welcome. You can still display it but as a readonly html tag - <input type="text" name="Total working hours" value="" readonly> so people can still see it's correct.

Comment: Oh and don't forget to close the question if you've got it working.

Comment: because #C is input too, I changed from .text to .value and it started to work. However, how can I explicitly turn those values as INTEGER, they are treated like STRING, because if I type 3 in field A and type 3 in field B, field C returns 33, which is correct for STRING

Comment: I've updated the code to parseInts, try it and see if it works.